# 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row when WHERE uses 2 columns for update

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update a single record by targeting 2 columns but I'm getting an error. The query is:

```
UPDATE friends 
SET status = "friend", befriended = "2013-09-26" 
WHERE u1_id = 6 AND u2_id = 1
```

What is wrong with this statement?

Comment: your query seems fine. Is that the whole query you execute? Also I can't find any subquery.

Comment: may be data collection have more than one record fulfilling the conditions...

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh! Thanks for your help guys! I checked the db and found that I had a trigger that was firing. Schoolboy error. Thanks again.